# How to open a document with applet code

Tags: java, applet

I have the following code but it seems that something is wrong. I am trying to figure it out but I am stack on it. Any help will be appreciated... thx

```
/* <applet code="showDemo" height=300 width=300> </applet> */
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShowDemo extends Applet
{
public void start() {
AppletContext ac = getAppletContext();
URL url = getCodeBase();
try{
ac.showDocument(new URL(url + "F:/Work_deepika/JavaVsAndroid.doc"));
}catch(MalformedURLException e){
showStatus("URL not Found ");
}
}
```

Comment: _something is wrong_ - care to elaborate?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "it seems that something is wrong". What does your code do that is wrong?